# C#, how do I modify the code to overcome the error at the end of the file download

Tags: c#

I am trying to doewnload a zip file from the site 
http://download.cms.gov/nppes/NPI_Files.html
The file can be obtained at he following link 
"download.cms.gov/nppes/NPPES_Data_Dissemination_December_2017.zip"
BTW- The file name changes with each month.
At the time of this post ( 2017-12 ) the file name was
"download.cms.gov/nppes/NPPES_Data_Dissemination_December_2017.zip"

I used for the following C# code.. works well but at the very end 
it throws and error and deleted the file at the destination.

The error message goes as follows:

> > > >
> > >       System.Net.WebException: An exception occurred during a WebClient request. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
> > >          at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
> > >          at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
> > >          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> > >          at System.Net.ConnectStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
> > >          at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBitsState.RetrieveBytes(Int32& bytesRetrieved)
> > >          at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBits(WebRequest request, Stream writeStream, CompletionDelegate completionDelegate, AsyncOperation asyncOp)
> > >          at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
> > >          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> > >          at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
> > >          at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(String address, String fileName)
> > >          at CmsNpiFileLoad.Program.Main(String[] args) in h:\ITFS2012\IT\CmsNpiFileLoad\CmsNpiFileLoad\Program.cs:line 92
> > >       <<<<

Here is the code: What am I doing wrong..Also if you have an alternative 
suggestion to use httpwebrequest please post some code..

```
                if(DirectoryForNpiFile.Right(1) != "\\" )  DirectoryForNpiFile+= "\\"; // add a \ to the end if needed.

        string Destinationfile = DirectoryForNpiFile + FirstPartOfFileNameToBeDownloaded + "_" + DateTime.Today.ToString("MMMM") + "_" + Convert.ToString(DateTime.Today.Year) + ".zip";


        Console.WriteLine("Start Downloading....");
        try
        {
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            //wc.DownloadFile(new System.Uri(CmsDownLoadSite), Destinationfile);

            wc.DownloadFile(CmsDownLoadSite, Destinationfile);
        }
        catch (WebException we)
        {
            // add some kind of error processing
            c.WriteToTempFileWhenCamsParameterIsON(we.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(we.ToString());
        }



        //String responseFromServer = null;
        //var url = CmsDownLoadSite;
        //var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        //request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36";
        //var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        //if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        //{
        //    using (var dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        //    {
        //        using (var reader = new StreamReader(dataStream))
        //            responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        //    }
        //}

        //if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(responseFromServer))
        //{
        //}
```

Comment: Do you also have access to the remote end?

Comment: @TobiasTheel: Highly unlikely, as that's a US government web site.

Answer (score 2):

> Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing
>   connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

This seems pretty clear. The remote host closed the connection before it was complete. You would need to know what the host was doing to know why.

When you say "deleted the file at the destination" are you sure it ever existed? Simply throwing an exception wouldn't delete a file.

Answer (score 0):

I ran these 2 lines of code in a test Windows Forms application, and it completed fine:

```
System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
wc.DownloadFile("http://download.cms.gov/nppes/NPPES_Data_Dissemination_December_2017.zip", @"C:\Users\bluem\Desktop\NPPES_Data_Dissemination_December_2017.zip");
```

Comment: Cool! Now can you tell me ( I like to see the code ) how to check whether the link is already there ( even before you start downloading ). The reason for that is the link changes every month. So I would like to check first whether the file exists!

Comment: That should probably be researched/asked as a separate question. How to determine whether an http link to a file is valid. My guess would be an exception handler around this, but that seems too obvious considering the code you've already tried.

Comment: I'm a little puzzled because I don't see my code here as any different than the code you've already tried.

Comment: BlueMonkMN: I used DownloadFileAsync, you used DownLoadFile. For some unknown reason the DownloadFileAsync does not give me error messages.  So my next question is how do I find whether that link is already in the page or not ( Probably use httpWebRequest ? )  i need some help here on coding